# Linked List Testing....Return type issue

Tags: java, class, junit, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have this code an IntLinkedList class

```
public class IntLinkedList {

    private Node head;

    public void addFirst(int data) {
        head = new Node(data, head);
    }

    public Node copy(){
       Node current = head; // used to iterate over original list
       Node newList = null; // head of the new list
       Node tail = null;    // point to last node in new list

       while (current != null)
       {
        // special case for the first new node
          if (newList == null)
          {
              newList = new Node(current.data, null);
              tail = newList;
          }
          else
          {
              tail.next = new Node(current.data, null);
              tail = tail.next;
          }
          current = current.next;
       }
       return newList;
    }


    private class Node  {
            int data;
            Node next;

        Node(int data, Node next) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to test the copy method with the following JUnit code

```
public class IntLinkedListTest {

    /** Reference to linked list under test */
    private IntLinkedList lst;

    /** Creates a linked list for testing. */
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        lst = new IntLinkedList();

        lst.addFirst(30);
        lst.addFirst(10);
        lst.addFirst(40);
        lst.addFirst(20);
    }

    /** Tests copying a non-empty list. */
    @Test
    public void testCopy() {
        IntLinkedList cpy = lst.copy();
        assertEquals(lst.toString(), cpy.toString());
    }
}
```

I want to get a list returned from the IntLinkedList class from the Copy() method and tested in JUnit. I tried returned type IntLinkedList and Object too but I keep getting errors like "Type mismatch: cannot convert from IntLinkedList.Node to IntLinkedList". I have very little experience with LinkedList but I'm experienced with java classes, references to objects, but this is new territory for me. Can anyone help?

Comment: `lst.copy()` in returing of type `Node` so it should be like `Node cpy = lst.copy();` 
if `assertEquals` does not work try iterating each element one by one and check. you code is looking good to me as now

Comment: checking equality based on `toString()` is bad practice. you should implement `equals()` and also decide what determines if two `Node`s are equal

Comment: @Jose I have posted my answer let me know if that works for you

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**:- You are comparing `Node` class toString with `IntLinkedList` class toString hence the Junit failure , Try overriding the `toString()` method of the Node and IntLinkedList class you will clearly see the stack trace as

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[IntLinkedList [head=Node [data=20, next=Node [data=40, next=Node [data=10, next=Node [data=30, next=null]]]]]]> but was:<[Node [data=20, next=Node [data=40, next=Node [data=10, next=Node [data=30, next=null]]]]]>
```

This Junit is working as expected

```
 @Test
    public void testCopy() {
        IntLinkedList.Node cpy = lst.copy();
        assertEquals(lst.copy().toString(), cpy.toString());
    }
```

**Edit**:- 
I have made one minor change to make `IntLinkedList.Node` work since your Node class is private, hence I changed the signature to static to make the junit work i.e.

```
static class Node  {
```

Comment: Thanks @Hades..You gave me several pointers for my final answer. I'm going to post it right now for others to see. If you have a recommendation, let me know. Thanks again

Comment: I upvoted the answer, but I don't think it will show up since I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Now you have.. Try again.

Answer (score 1):

This is the final IntLinkedList copy() method with a more elegant solution to my problem. I'm only posting the copy() method since the IntLinkedList class stays the same and JUnit testing stays the same. Note: In the IntLinkedList class the only thing that changes is the copy() method

```
public IntLinkedList copy(){
    IntLinkedList newList = new IntLinkedList();
    Node current = head;    // used to iterate over original list
    Node tail = null;   // point to last node in new list

    while (current != null)
    {
        // special case for the first new node
        if (newList.head == null)
        {
            newList.head = new Node(current.data, null);
            tail = newList.head;
        }
        else
        {
            tail.next = new Node(current.data, null);
            tail = tail.next;
        }
        current = current.next;
    }

    return newList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm.

Your `copy()` should imho not return `Node` but `IntLinkedList`
So you need to adjust your code of `copy()` accordingly.

Also, implement `equals()` (and `hashCode()`) in your `IntLinkedList` class.
The equals implementation should match your expectation of when two `IntLinkedList` are equal.

Later in the test, use `InLinkedList copy = copy(orig)` and compare the result with `Assert.equals(orig, copy)`.